# Latvian Visa for Indian National In Zagreb

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, croatia, latvia

Hi I am Indian national and will be traveling to Riga for research in a company.
I am currently in Zagreb. 
I was not able to find official document list for the application of visa.

Can anyone help me out ?

Also I heard Indians don't need to pay visa fees if they are traveling to Latvia for research. Can anybody confirm this ?

Comment: It should be about the same as any other Schengen visa. The more interesting question will be: To what consulate are you going to submit the visa application? The [diplomatic mission serving Croatia is in Budapest, Hungary](https://www.mfa.gov.lv/en/hungary). But how do you go there without a Schengen visa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was the reply from the Department of Immigration Latvia.

> As mentioned before: If you reside in Croatia as a researcher (you
>   have a long-stay visa or a temporary residence permit issued by
>   Croatia for that purpose) you can travel to Latvia and stay here until
>   180 days without visa in case when research work in Latvia is in the
>   frame of the same project and you can documentary prove it.
>
> Here is references to the corresponding legal acts:
>
> ```
> “A researcher to whom a long-stay visa or a temporary residence permit has been issued in another Member State of the European Union
> ```
>
> in relation to research is entitled to reside in the Republic of
>   Latvia within the validity period of the aforementioned visa or
>   temporary residence permit for the purpose of conducting the research
>   work for a period of 180 days in any time period of 360 days.”
>   (https://likumi.lv/ta/en/en/id/68522-immigration-law, Immigration Law,
>   Section 5.2).
>
> ```
> (Directive (EU) 2016/801 of the European Parliament and of the Council of 11 May 2016 on the conditions of entry and residence of
> ```
>
> third-country nationals for the purposes of research, studies,
>   training, voluntary service, pupil exchange schemes or educational
>   projects and au pairing.
>
> That means you do not have to apply for a visa (Schengen C visa) for
>   travelling to Latvia when purpose of entry is the same research work
>   as in Croatia.

**Researchers don't neet visa to travel to Latvia for 180 days**

Comment: I wonder if it is same for other EU countries

Comment: This rule is not known to many countries and the border police will create a lot of problems for you if you don't have valid Schengen visa.

Answer (score 3):

Latvia is a [Schengen state](https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/visa-policy/schengen_visa_en) and most Indian nationals require a Schengen visa to visit Latvia.The Latvian Embassy in New Delhi has a detailed webpage on short stay visas, also detailing document requirements [here](https://www.mfa.gov.lv/en/newdelhi/consular-section/visa).

However, since you live in Croatia and Latvia does not maintain an embassy there, instead the [Latvian embassy in Budapest](https://www.mfa.gov.lv/en/hungary) covers covers Slovenia, Croatia and Montenegro. In this case, you may have to apply for a visa through another Schengen state that has a consular presence in Croatia.

I suggest you contact the Latvian embassy in Hungary by email or phone for details about your visa application.

Wish you good luck!

Comment: I came to know from this link https://www.mfa.gov.lv/en/consular-information/applying-for-a-visa that I can apply from a consulate. There is one consulate in Zagreb. Consulate of the Republic of Latvia to the Republic of Croatia, Zagreb 5. Ravnice 10 10000 Zagreb CROATIA. I am going to write to them as well as the embassy in Budapest. Thanks for the reply

Comment: Bad Luck .... Latvian embassy in Budapest does not issue visa and the consulate is also of the same nature. They are telling me to fly back to India for applying the visa. I feel really stupid.. Its not like India is 2 hrs drive from Croatia